# Is there a fast in-memory queue I can use that swaps items as it reaches a certain size?

Tags: c++, c, io, cuda, message-queue

I've been using c/c++/cuda for less than a week  and not familiar with all the options available in terms of libraries(sorry if my question is too wacky or impossible).  Here's my problem, I have a process that takes data and analyzes it then does 1 of 3 things, (1) saves the results, (2) discards the results or (3) breaks the data down and sends it back to be processed.

Often option (3) creates a lot of data and I very quickly exceed the memory available to me(my server is 16 gigs) so the way I got around that was to setup a queue server(rabbitmq) that I would send and receive work from(it swaps the queue once it reaches a certain size of memory). This worked perfectly when I used small servers with faster nics to transfer the data, but lately I have been learning and converting my code from Java to c/c++ and running it on a GPU which has made the queues a big bottleneck.  The bottleneck was obviously the network io(profiling on cheap systems showed high cpu usage and similar on old gpu's but new faster cpus/gpus are not getting utilized as much and network IO is steady at 300-400/mbs).  So I decided to try to eliminate the network totally and run the queue server locally on the server which made it faster but I suspect it could be even more faster if I used a solution that didn't rely on external network services(even if I am running them locally). It may not work but I want to experiment.

So my question is, is there anything that I can use like a queue that I can remove entries as I read them but also swaps the queue to disk once it reaches a certain size(but keeps the in-memory queue always full so I don't have to wait to read from disk)?  When learning about Cuda, there are many examples of researchers running analysis on huge datasets, any ideas of how they keep data coming in at the fastest rate for the system to process(I imagine they aren't bound by disk/network otherwise faster gpu's wouldn't really give them magnitudes increase in performance)?

Does anything like this exist?

p.s. if it helps, so far I have experimented with rabbitmq(too slow for my situation), apollo mq(good but still network based), reddis(really liked it but cannot exceed physical memory), playing with mmap(), and I've also compressed my data to get better throughput. I know general solutions but I'm wondering if there's something native to c/c++, cuda or a library I can use(*ideally, I would have a queue in Cuda global memory that swapped to the host memory that swapped to the disk so the GPU's would always be at full speed* but that maybe wishful thinking). If there's anything else you can think of let me know and I'd enjoy experimenting with it(if it helps, I develop on a Mac and run it on linux).

Comment: [Boost.CircularBuffer](http://www.boost.org/libs/circular_buffer/)?

Comment: Maybe STXXL? http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks ildjarn & Roger, I'll experiment with both.  @andrewcooke I think it ultimately needs to swap to disk b/c the size of the queue exceeds physical memory but if there's another faster way then I'll give it a try.

Comment: you should be able to do better than paging - a smart solution will be able to read off disk before the data are needed; paging will stall when you start reading from the page that's swapped out.

Comment: @andrewcooke that is exactly what I want. The queue servers seem to be able to keep in-memory queues constant and page extra to disk(but also replenish in memory queue when it gets empty as well). I'm not sure how to do it without having to go over a network.

Comment: The CUDA API is naturally asynchronous and you can overlap computation and memory transfers to- and from- the GPU just using standard API calls (see streams in the documentation). So is your question is really about having some sort host side memory FIFO buffer that will automagically keep itself full from a disk or network source and that your CUDA "workers" can push and pull work from via the standard CUDA APIs? It would seem this really isn't a CUDA question in that case.....

Comment: @Lostsout yes, i understand - what you're looking for sounds reasonable to me, but i don't know of anything that would work.

Comment: @talonmies your completely right, I just added Cuda to it because I thought there was a slight chance someone(computation researcher for example) had a solution specific to me. It would be ideal but if I get a c/c++ solution then I would just stream it back and forth from memory to cuda(and have the extra memory swapped).  This does seem like a problem Cuda users would approach, Cuda can process data faster than memory so I'm sure users have tried to figure out ways to keep their memory full to max performance on Cuda.

Comment: @RogerDahl jeez, two words and a link, but 'nuff said. Why not make that an answer?  _Software: Practice and Experience_ is not a lightweight journal.

Comment: @jthill: And a question mark. The question mark has to count for something, right? Are you suggesting I need to read the book? :) I didn't add my comment as an answer as it doesn't really answer the question. STXXL is just a building block with which such a solution can be implemented.

Comment: @RogerDahl no, my comment was straight up.  His question is "So my question is, is there anything that I can use like a queue that I can remove entries as I read them but also swaps the queue to disk once it reaches a certain size(but keeps the in-memory queue always full so I don't have to wait to read from disk)?" and it looks to me as if STXXL is exactly what he's asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me suggest something quite different.

Building a custom solution would not be excessively hard for an experienced programmer, but it is probably impossible for an inexperienced or even intermediate programmer to produce something robust and reliable.

Have you considered a DBMS?

For small data sets it will all be cached in memory.  As it grows, the DBMS will have some very sophisticated caching/paging techniques.  You get goodies like sorting/prioritisation, synchronisation/sharing for free.

A really well-written custom solution will be much faster than a DBMS, but will have huge costs in developing and maintaining the custom solution.  Spend a bit of time optimising and tuning the DBMS and it starts looking pretty fast and will be very robust.

It may not fit your needs, but I'd suggest having a long hard look at a DBMS before you reject it.

Comment: My knee jerk reaction was "eew no!" and then I just let it sink in and that turned into "you know what? that's a nice hack and a very good idea for less-experienced developers." Have a +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

There's an open source implementation of the Standard Template Library containers that's created to address exactly this problem.

[STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) nearly transparently swaps data to the disk for any of the standard STL containers. It's very well-written and well-maintained, and is very easy to adapt/migrate your code to given its similarity to the STL.

Another option is to use the existing STL containers but specify a disk-backed allocator. All the STL containers have a template parameter for the STL allocator, which specifies how the memory for entries is stored. There's a good disk-backed STL allocator that's on the tip of my tongue, but I can't seem to find via Google (I'll update this if/when I do).

Edit: I see Roger had actually already mentioned this [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568250/is-there-a-fast-in-memory-queue-i-can-use-that-swaps-items-as-it-reaches-a-certa/10624390#comment13682411_10568250).

Comment: I used STXXL for a project and was very happy with it. Thank you to the authors for awesome work. The reason though, that I didn't add it as answer, was that I thought it used only the disk and hardly any memory. That is, the question was about a queue that will seamlessly expand to disk storage only when memory is exhausted. Can STXXL do that?

Comment: Hey, did you finally remember the name of the disk-backed STL allocator you mentioned?